# code2flow can't find graphviz in the path

Tags: python, graphviz

I'm trying to get [some code](https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow) to run and I'm triggering an error:

```
if not isInstalled('dot') and not isInstalled('dot.exe'):
    print "You must have graphviz (specifically dot) installed to run code2flow"
    sys.exit(1)
```

which calls

```
def isInstalled(program):
    def is_exe(fpath):
        return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)

    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
        path = path.strip('"')
        exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
        if is_exe(exe_file):
            return True

    return False
```

But I don't understand why this is failing. My path contains graphviz

> > echo %PATH%
>
> ...;c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;...

and the file is present

> > dir "c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe"
>
> Directory of c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin
>
> 04/14/2014  09:22 AM             7,680 dot.exe

Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: What about `python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["PATH"])'` and `python -c 'import os.path; print(os.path.isfile("c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe"))'`

Comment: How does it fail? I tried your code and after importing "os" and testing for 'HelpPane.exe' (This exe I found in the windows- folder) I get the "True" you look for.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Flipping your quotes so Windows can handle it the first prints the path, which does include `;c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;`. The second is `False` and I don't know why.

Comment: @am2 `isInstalled('dot.exe')` is`False` despite the file existing in a directory on the path.

Comment: @Charles: Of course, I only wanted to test your code on my system (where dot.com is not installed). And your code works for me (with another executable). If I were you I would add a "print(exe_file)", a "print(os.path.isfile(fpath))" and a "print(os.access(fpath, os.X_OK))" to ensure, there is no surprise. ANd maybe I would try it out with an "exe" to ensure, that "com" is not the problem.

Comment: @am2 There are no `com`s involved, the file is a standard PE named `dot.exe`. I'll try some tests.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where I read "com" ... But your code seems to be correct, is working fine on my machine. The only Thing I can imagine is, that there are any unicode mistakes or something like that. Thats why I would print as much as possible. So you can copy/paste to run it on the command prompt to ensure, you did not misspell anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have this error, too.

I try to run the command:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

It's okay now.

My way to install code2flow is by using pip install.

But the codes inside ./ur/path/to/code2flow is written with python2.

Thus!